# Installed ffmpeg to /home/user/bin

Tags: compiling, ffmpeg

I followed [These Instructions](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) to compile ffmpeg from source.  Now I have a folder named /home/hilarie/bin with stuff in it

```
$ which ffmpeg
/home/hilarie/bin/ffmpeg
$ /home/hilarie/bin/ffmpeg
ffmpeg version N-87132-g1dc33c1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/home/hilarie/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/home/hilarie/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/hilarie/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/home/hilarie/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55. 74.100 / 55. 74.100
  libavcodec     57.104.100 / 57.104.100
  libavformat    57. 79.100 / 57. 79.100
  libavdevice    57.  8.100 / 57.  8.100
  libavfilter     6.101.100 /  6.101.100
  libswscale      4.  7.103 /  4.  7.103
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'
```

It appears to be installed correctly, but what can I do to get it out of my home directory so I don't accidentally delete it or something.

Comment: That was by design, according to the instructions. Is there a reason you compiled ffmpeg instead of running `sudo apt install ffmpeg`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next time when compiling you can set the location with:

```
./configure --prefix=/custom/location
```

To fix your case just use `mv` command and move it to the `/usr/local/bin` with:

```
sudo mv /home/hilarie/bin/ffmpeg  /usr/local/bin
```

But I would advise you `uninstall` it from the current location,

```
make uninstall
```

and re-compile and install with:

```
 ./configure --prefix=/custom/location
 sudo make install
```

this will ensure that if you wish to remove it, it can be found.